# import ringtone into emulator (android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, ringtone

I am using Android Studio. I am trying to test ringtones on emulator before working on a real device.

Does anyone know how to import ringtones into an emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you internet connection on your system. If yes then you can download any music on the emulator by opening the browser in your emulator.

Another way is that you can put any music file in the raw folder of your project and use it as your requirement.

Comment: In addition you can not receive or make any calls on emulator. You can only play the ringtone for testing.

Comment: Thanks, I am testing the ringtone with Notification. Could I use the raw folder to work with RingtonePreference?
Download from the internet is too slow.

Comment: Yes ofcourse you can. And if my answer is helpful to you. Please don't forget to vote up or mark my answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can just drag and drop the files from your pc desktop or any folder into emulator, the files will be saved in downloads folder

Comment: Thanks, I think it doesn't work. I am running the Nexus 4 with API 16

Comment: i have tried it, and importing files from pc to emulator works for me